# dual monitors on remote session

Tags: windows-7, windows

my laptop resoultion is 1920 X 1080 and my desktop resoultion is 1680 X 1050.

When I remote into my laptop from desktop, then I cant extend the screen for the remote session to my second monitor. Both machines have windows 7.

I have set the resolution of both machines to same . But it does not make any difference. What I have to do use dual monitors for the remote session on windows 7

Answer (score 2):

If you're using RDP, in the Connection window, expand Options, select the Display tab, and select "Use all my monitors for the remote session".

RDP is different from VNC in this way. VNC essentially copies the display output from the host computer and sends it remote. RDP creates it's own configuration and sends it as it wants. They are different tools with different purposes and strengths.

For instance, if your source machine has one monitor and your viewer computer has two monitors and you select the "Use all my monitors" option, you'll have two screens-worth of display even though the source computer doesn't have two screens. RDP depends on the settings of the viewer computer to determine how much graphical information is needs to send.

Comment: The monitor resolution doesn't matter, but when you log back in locally, sometimes things get messed up.

Comment: Yes. VNC by default shows an exact copy of the source screen. RDP creates a new session on the computer and redirects the visual output based on the configuration of the viewer or user preferences.